# Number of complex embeddings of a certain number field

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, complex-multiplication

Let $K$ be an imaginary quadratic field with class number 1 and $E/K$ be an elliptic curve with CM by $\mathcal{O}_K$. Consider the number field $F=K(E[p])$. Can $r_2(F) =1$?

Comment: $K$ doesn't have any real embedding so $F$ has $[F:Q]/2= [F:K]$ pairs of complex embeddings

Comment: So it is obvious that [F:Q] is a totally imaginary extension?